# transaction - read lock

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

Suppose I have a transaction with 2 select requesting 2 different tables

begin tran

select ... from t1 where ...

select .... from t2 where ...

Is there a transaction level which guarantees that the 2 selects are done "as if" it was requested at the same time ? If we want for instance to retrieve consistent data between t1 and t2.
Do we need to explicitely lock even if we are inside a transaction ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: use serialization isolation level. then you will see data as they were at the time when your transaction started.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle, you can also use

```
 set transaction read only;
```

before issuing your selects.  This will guarantee repeatable reads no matter what is going on with the database.

[Here's a good example.](http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/oracle/Set-READ-ONLY-Transaction.html)

[And another.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/api/doc/PC_22/ch08.htm#toc108)

Finally, [here's a good run-through](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-jan/o65asktom-082389.html) of the various isolation levels that Oracle provides from Ask Tom.